# How do I call this.function from inside the .map() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm starting my adventure with React. I have a trouble with calling the function ***rvKey*** from inside the map function.

Finally, this function will be responsible for removing the button that is clicked. But so far, I cannot even console.log a message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rvKey' of undefined
```

I'm using webpack and material-ui.

```js
class Search extends React.Component {  
    state = {
        keywords: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    };

    rvKey = () => {
        console.log('111');
    // remove this element
    }

    keywords = () => {
        return this.state.keywords.map(function(object, i){
            return (
                <Button dense mini raised color="default" key={i}>
                    {object}
                    <Close
                        onClick={this.rvKey}
                        className="icon small"
                    />
                </Button>
            )
        })
    }



    render(){
        return (
       <Input>
        {this.keywords()} 
       </Input>
    );
    };
};
```

Comment: Just change your `map` callback into an arrow function. :-) See the linked question's answers for details.